# Getting Null Error when deleting the first node of Doubly Linked List in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to remove a node from a doubly linked list based on given String parameter in Java, but the problem is when deleting nodes from index 1+, there is no Null Error except when I delete the index 0 node, I always get Null Error.
Why? (The header of this linked list is (null, null, Node1)

```
 public boolean remove(String item){
        
        boolean isFound = false;
        
        if(header.next == null)
            return false;
        
        Node temp = header;
        
        while(temp.next !=  null) {
            temp = temp.next;
            if(temp.value.equals(item)) {
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(temp == null || isFound == false)
            return false;
        
        Node p = temp.previous;
        Node n = temp.next;
        p.next = n;
        
        if(n != null) {
            n.previous = p;
        }
        
        temp = null;
        
        return true;
    }

    public void addLast(String item){
        
         Node n = new Node();
         n.value = item;
         
         if(header.next == null) {
             header.next = n;
         }
         else {
             Node temp = header;
             while(temp.next != null)
                 temp = temp.next;
             
             temp.next = n;
             n.previous = temp;
             temp = header;
         }
        
    }

    class Node {
        
        String value;
        Node next;
        Node previous;
        
        public String toString() {
            return value == null ? "null" : value;
        }
    }

 public static void main(String[] args){
        DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();
        list.addLast("Bob");
        list.addLast("Steve");
        list.addLast("Harry");
        list.remove("Bob");
        System.out.println(list);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `header` represents the first item in the linked list.
I believe it's because you did not check if header itself already is the item that we want to remove.
In addLast() you also did not account for if header was null (When no items are in the list)

```
public class DoublyLinkedList {
    public Node header;
    public boolean remove(String item){
        if (header == null) // add this code
            return false;
        if (header.value.equals(item)) { // add this code
            header = header.next;
            header.previous = null;
            return true;
        }
        boolean isFound = false;
        
        if(header.next == null)
            return false;
        
        Node temp = header;
        
        while(temp.next !=  null) {
            temp = temp.next;
            if(temp.value.equals(item)) {
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(temp == null || isFound == false)
            return false;
        
        Node p = temp.previous;
        Node n = temp.next;
        p.next = n;
        
        if(n != null) {
            n.previous = p;
        }
        
        temp = null;
        
        return true;
    }
    
    public void addLast(String item){
         Node n = new Node();
         n.value = item;
         if (header == null) { // add this code
            header = n;
         }
         else if(header.next == null) {
             header.next = n;
         }
         else {
             Node temp = header;
             while(temp.next != null)
                 temp = temp.next;
             
             temp.next = n;
             n.previous = temp;
             temp = header;
         }
    }
    
    class Node {
        String value;
        Node next;
        Node previous;
        
        public String toString() {
            return value == null ? "null" : value;
        }
    }

    public void showAll() {
        if (header == null) return;
        Node temp = header;

        while (temp.next != null) {
            System.out.println(temp);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();
        list.addLast("Bob");
        list.addLast("Steve");
        list.addLast("Harry");
        list.remove("Bob");
        list.showAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: I still received error after adding this line of code. The linkedlist that I'm working on, they require me to let the node of header & previous of header = null, so that's the reason I did not check it.

Comment: after adding all 3 segments as stated in the edited post above?
In that case can I trouble you to state all the codes that you are using in your post?

Comment: for some reasons, I tried your methods and other many methods, but It still did not work. However, I tried init null data to the header at the beginning, and the code ran normally.